# create deep network in matlab with logsig layer instead of softmax layer

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, softmax

I want to create a deep classification net, but my classes aren't mutually exclusive (that is what sofmaxlayer do).
Is it possible to define a non mutually exclusive classification layer (i.e., a data can be in more than one class)?
One way to do it, it would be with a logsig function in the classification layer, instead of a softmax, but I have no idea how to acomplish that....

Answer (score 0):

In CNN you can have multiple class in last layer as you know. But if I understand correctly your need in last layer an out put with that is in a range of numbers instead of 1 or 0 for each class. Its mean you need regression. If your labels support this task it's OK and you can do it with regression just like what happen in bounding box regression for localization. And you don't need soft-max in last layer. just use other activation functions that produce sufficient out put for your task.

Comment: I though about a regression layer, but i'm not so sure yet. My output for each class should be a number between 0 and 1, but unlike the softmaxLayer in which the sum of the outputs of each class is one (and therefore you have mutually exclusive classes), i don't have that restriction (making an input be in more that one class possible). I can accomplish this with a timedelay net, but complexity of the input signal tells me that a deep network should be best.

Comment: So You can simply change activation functions in last layer. Eliminate Soft-max and replace it by Sigmoid. Sigmoid produce an out put between 0 and 1 and each output is independent.

Comment: i'll do that, but matlab doesn't have a logsigLayer, and that's why i'm asking

Comment: I think you don't need a new layer (logsigLayer) like Soft-max layer. you need give output of fully connected layer and forward them in matlab sigmoid function ( y = sigmf(x,[a c]) ) . I hope it's work

Comment: that's the thing, matlab requieres an output layer (currently only softmax is available). Otherwise there are errors in training...